# In google analytics premium account can we change campaign name of historical data?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to change campaign name of historical data and restore same going forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once Google analytics data has been inserted there is no way to update it.   Your historical data is now set in stone.

You should fix what you are inserting now there is no way to change what is already inserted.